# creating nested json objects from a list

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to understand how to take a list and convert that into a nested JSON object.

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "Name1": [
    {
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value"
    }
   ],
}
```

So far my thinking as gone as follows, convert the list to dictionary using comprehension and splitting key value pairs.

```
list1 = ['key value', 'key value', 'key value']
dict1 = dict(item.split(" ") for item in list1)
```

I then thought converting that into a JSON object would be something similar to:

```
print json.loads(dict1)
```

However, Im not sure how to create the "Name1" parent key. And it seems google is being particularly helpful. Im sure there is something simple im missing, any pointers would be appreacited.

**EDIT**

Included a list for reference

Comment: Please first show the data (input). Right now it is hard to see how your input maps on your output...

Comment: Good point, added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply put them in **another dictionary**, and **use a new list**. So:

```
import json

list1 = ['key1 value1', 'key2 value2', 'key3 value3']
dict1 = {'Name1': [dict(item.split(" ",1) for item in list1)] }
#       ^ dict    ^ list with 1 element            end list ^ ^ end dict
json.dumps(dict1)
```

And this produces:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(dict1))
{"Name1": [{"key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "key1": "value1"}]}
```

> **Notes**:
>
> 1. A dictionary can only contain **different keys** (both in JSON and Python);
> 2. You better split with `.split(" ",1)` since if the value contains spaces, these are all seen as still a single value.
> 3. dictionaries are unordered, so the order of th keys can be shuffled.